# Groovy Dependency management

Tags: maven, groovy, dependencies, groovy-grape

I am quite new to groovy and need to clarify on the Groovy Dependency management.

Here is the summary according to [my "Homework"](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/grape.html):

- Groovy Dependency management is as simple as adding an annotation to the script. E.g.
  `@Grab('org.springframework:spring-orm:3.2.5.RELEASE')`
- Grape will then quickly add the dependencies from maven repository to your classpath

So, is adding to my groovy script the dependency annotation is *all* that I need, and Groovy/Grape will take care of the rest, when I run my Groovy script, right? (or there are some prerequisites, like I can't put my groovy script randomly anywhere, but has to be at a specific place like within a Groovy project, etc)

Second question, how to translate Maven dependency to Groovy/Grape dependency annotation?

For e..g., this is the Maven dependency for Opencsv:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>5.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Does that translate to `@Grab('com.opencsv:opencsv:5.2')`?

Third question,

suppose I need to import `org.apache.commons.collections.primitives.ArrayIntList`, how can I come up with a Groovy/Grape dependency annotation as

`@Grab(group='commons-primitives', module='commons-primitives', version='1.0')`

I.e., where can I found the connection between `org.apache.commons.collections.primitives.ArrayIntList` and `commons-primitives`?

And finally,

where would Groovy/Grape store the downloaded .jar files?

Comment: this site contains dependency declaration for different languages including Grape/Grab: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.opencsv/opencsv/5.2

Comment: Central https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.opencsv/opencsv/5.3/jar. has that also see on the right side...

Comment: and yes, you can put your script anywhere, and run it with `groovy path/scriptName.groovy`. if you need local dependencies then use `-cp` to set classpath

Comment: and for the last question `@Grab(group='commons-primitives', module='commons-primitives', version='1.0')` is equivalent to `@Grab('commons-primitives:commons-primitives:1.0')`, the latter is just shorter.

Comment: You have four reasonable questions here, which is about three too many for a Stack Overflow post.  I'm going to vote to close this, though I think any or all of these would be fair individual posts.